# Objective-C - UIBarButtonItem Crashes, weird crash log

Tags: objective-c

I have an UIBarButtonItem that is crashing, but I can't figure out what is happening. It's not generating any error on the debugger and its crash log is not symbolicating some parts. This is the crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x354ba88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37861259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x354ba789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   Foundation                      0x34fa23ff -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 87
4   Exame_iPhone                    0x000b9029 0x4b000 + 450601
5   Exame_iPhone                    0x000b9071 0x4b000 + 450673
6   Exame_iPhone                    0x0010a60d 0x4b000 + 783885
7   Exame_iPhone                    0x0010aa7b 0x4b000 + 785019
8   Exame_iPhone                    0x00069ff3 0x4b000 + 126963
9   CoreFoundation                  0x354143fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53
10  UIKit                           0x32f09e07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63
11  UIKit                           0x32fcf5e7 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 119
12  CoreFoundation                  0x354143fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53
13  UIKit                           0x32f09e07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63
14  UIKit                           0x32f09dc3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
15  UIKit                           0x32f09da1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
16  UIKit                           0x32f09b11 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 493
17  UIKit                           0x32f0a449 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 477
18  UIKit                           0x32f0892b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319
19  UIKit                           0x32f08319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381
20  UIKit                           0x32eee695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357
21  UIKit                           0x32eedf3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
22  GraphicsServices                0x370ad22b PurpleEventCallback + 883
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3548e523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3548e4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3548d313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
26  CoreFoundation                  0x354104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3541036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
28  GraphicsServices                0x370ac439 GSEventRunModal + 137
29  UIKit                           0x32f1ccd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
30  Exame_iPhone                    0x0004c23b 0x4b000 + 4667
31  Exame_iPhone                    0x0004c1e0 0x4b000 + 4576


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35d7032c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x328bc208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x328b5298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35872f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35870346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37861350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x358703be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3587044a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3587181e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x378612a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35410506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35410366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x370ac432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x32f1ccce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  Exame_iPhone                    0x0004c234 0x4b000 + 4660
15  Exame_iPhone                    0x0004c1d8 0x4b000 + 4568
```

Does anybody know what is going on?

Regards!

Comment: Figure out why it's not symbolicating otherwise you are shooting in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

An assertion fails in the non-symbolicated lines, probably in your own method. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of your button method and step through until you get the crash.

Comment: I already tried, it's not entering in the method set for this button!

Comment: Does the method exist exactly how you've specified it? Try replacing it with a simlpe `buttonClicked:(id)sender` method, does that work?